# Serializing and Searching Object Collections

Tags: vb.net, object, collections

I would appreciate if somebody could answer some questions regarding storing and searching object collections please. If you could give a basic example of any suggestions I would be very grateful.

Storing:

I'm writing an application which needs to search Active Directory for computer objects, and I'm storing them in a collection of objects. I want to save the computer objects collection along with additional information which is not stored in Active Directory (e.g. the computer's MAC address) for the next time the application is run. I also want to save a list of OU's.

Here is my object collection so far (It will have more properties). What is the best method of saving the collection? Preferably not using a database or will saving to a file have a drastic performance impact?

Or is there a better way to do what I have below?

```
Public Class Computer

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property FQDN As String
    Public Property Path As String

End Class

Public Class ComputerCollection
    Inherits Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Sub Add(ByVal computer As Computer) 'Adds a new computer object to the collection
        List.Add(computer)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Searching:

I have a layout similar to ADUC with a tree view of OU's and a list view displaying computer objects in the selected OU. The following code loops through the computer object collection checking if the path of the computer object matches the selected OU path and then displays them in the list view.

Is this the best method in terms of performance? or is there a faster way?

```
Private Sub tvOU_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvOU.AfterSelect

    lvComputers.Items.Clear()

    If tvOU.SelectedNode.Name > "" Then

        For Each computerObj In computers

            If computerObj.Path.ToString.Replace("CN=" + computerObj.Name + ",", "") = tvOU.SelectedNode.Name Then
                Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
                lvItem.Text = computerObj.Name
                lvComputers.Items.Add(lvItem)
            End If

        Next

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you're using VB.NET 2002 or 2003, don't inherit `CollectionBase`.  Either just create a `List(Of Computer)` or, if you want a custom collection, inherit `Collection(Of Computer)`.

Comment: One optomization you could so is add a CNName property to your class so you wold not have to do that string mashing in a loop, just iterate your List or Collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `List(Of Computer)` is indeed all you need unless there is some other unknown requirement. Saving is very simple using serialization for this type of thing, and would work the same for a `List` or `Collection<T>`.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class ComputersCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of Computer)
    ' NOT the crude thing in the VB NameSpace

    ' there is almost nothing to add: item, add and remove
    ' are in the base class
    ' ... perhaps saving and retrieving them by a key (name)
    ' which may do away with the search procedure in the posted code

End Class

Private Computers As New Collection(Of Computer)
' or
Private Computers As New List(Of Computer)
```

The other part, saving your collection, can be simple with serialization.  First, you will have to add the Serializable attribute to your Computer class:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Computer
```

If you forget, you get the error `Class foobar is not marked as serializable`.  Save to disk:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Private myComputerFile As String = ...

Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
Using fs As New FileStream(myComputerFile , FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    bf.Serialize(fs, Computers)
End Using
```

Then you can recreate the List or Collection just as easily; this time the List:

```
' ToDo: add a check to skip if file is not there
' as in the first time run
Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
Using fs As New FileStream(myComputerFile , FileMode.Open)
    Computers = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Computers))
End Using
```

Alternatively you can use the XML serializer to create an XML File or use the faster, smarter binary serializer is ProtoBuf-Net

Comment: Don't you have to serialize (put the declaration at the top of the class) before you can serialize it. I thought you did to tell it the class is serialized?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR  yes, it needs the `Attribute`, his class was not part of the answer, so I forgot.  Added it, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, I've got it working now :)