# VB.Net My.Settings custom type for list of saved SQL servers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to use My.Settings to save a list of authenticated servers and their information, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make my custom type.

I have a class right now called SqlServer that has these three fields:

```
 Public ServerName As String
 Public UserName As String
 Public Password As String
```

Each time I connect to a SQL server using SQL Authentication, I want to save that server and the login information. This means that I need a custom type that is a collection of SqlServer's in My.Settings.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class SQLServerList
  Inherits List(Of SQLServer)
  Implements IComparable(Of SQLServer)

  Public Function CompareTo(ByVal SqlServerInfo As SQLServer) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of MyProjectName.SQLServer).CompareTo
    ...
  End Function
End Class
```

Am I on the right track here by inheriting List? And what kinds of properties/fields will I need in order to get this thing to function as I want it to? Thank you.

Comment: You are probably better off serializing your collection class. Such as [Storing Object Collections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25879442/1070452).  Personally, I'd make `SQLServerList` a collection class which *implements* a :List<T>

Comment: Ok, this is what I have right now: Public Class SqlServerList Inherits Collection(Of SqlServer) Implements IList(Of SqlServer).. I am pretty sure this is what you were getting at

Comment: you dont need the list if you inherit `Collection(Of T)`.  What I meant by implement a List(T) was a simple `Private myList(Of SQLServer)`.  Your class would expose Add etc methods to manager the list. The class could have a Save method to do the serialization (2-3 lines of code) and a Shared method to load them. The Collection<T> will totally work though.

Comment: Since you have pws in there, do you want/need/think it should be encrypted?

Comment: Yes, I do want to encrypt it. Do you recommend this: System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: just wrap your filestream (assuming you are serialziing) in a cryptostream

Comment: very cool, I'll do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a collection class, it is pretty easy to have it serialize the contents itself.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

<Serializable>
Public Class Server
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property Password As String
End Class
```

A simple collection class:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Servers
    Private myList As List(Of Server)

    Public Sub New()
        myList = New List(Of Server)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(svr As Server)
        myList.Add(svr)
    End Sub

    ' no reason it cant also create server objects for you
    Public Sub Add(sname As String, uname As String, pw As String)
        myList.Add(New Server With {.Name = sname, .UserName = uname, .Password = pw})
    End Sub

    'toDo Contains, Count, Item etc as needed

    Public Sub Save(mypath As String)
        Using fs As New FileStream(mypath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
            bf.Serialize(fs, myList)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function Load(mypath As String) As Int32
        'ToDo: check if file exists
        Using fs As New FileStream(mypath, FileMode.Open)
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
            myList = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Server))
        End Using

        If myList IsNot Nothing Then
            Return myList.Count
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

The `<Serializable>` attribute is required for the `BinaryFormatter`.  Different serializers (json, ProtoBuf-NET) may have their own.

The "magic" is in the `Save` and `Load` methods which serialize or deserialize the internal list of objects.  Just a few lines of code to load/save 1 or 1000 items.  Its a great alternative to a database for small amounts of data.

Testing for a roundtrip:

```
    Dim svrs As New Servers
    svrs.Add("SqlSS1", "ziggy", "foo")
    svrs.Add("SqlSS2", "zacky", "bar")
    svrs.Add("SqlSS3", "zoey", "baz")

    svrs.Save("C:\Temp\SSvrs.bin")

    ' now load to a new Servers collection
    ' to test the round trip
    Dim svrs2 As New Servers
    Dim sCount = svrs2.Load("C:\Temp\SSvrs.bin")

    For n = 0 To sCount  - 1
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}   {2} ", svrs2(n).Name, svrs2(n).UserName, svrs2(n).Password)
    Next
```

Output:

> SqlSS1  ziggy   foo
>   SqlSS2  zacky   bar
>   SqlSS3  zoey   baz

I used the BinaryFormatter (for no real reason) but ProtoBuf-NET or XMLSerializer will also work.  Since the data is all string, you may want to encrypt them (wrap the filestream in a cryptostream).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save some class you defined into My.Settings you basically need to meet the same requirements as for any XML-serializable class.

- Your class must be Serializable.
- Your class must have a public default constructor that take no parameters.
- Any property in your class of a type from the .NET must be Serializable.
- Any class contained in your class must meet these same requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Benchmark test, serialize object to binary-file, XML-file and XML string:**

- Write 500.000 objects to binaryfile (1954ms / 23MB)
- Write 500.000 objects to XML file (660ms / 46MB)
- Write 500.000 objects to XML-string (847ms, process 38MB->348MB)

Surprised to see it takes longer time to write a binary file than XML file. I would expect .Net just dump memory to file without any processing and conversion.  Maybe there is a better binary serializer than the one used?

Although it was expected to be smaller. XML file "only" have a overhead of 100%.

Also surprising to see writing an XML file is faster than writing to a string in memory.

Am sure my code could be optimized as it's very strange, feel free contribute :-)

Object to be serialized:

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class oNames
    Public Shared cNames As New List(Of oName)

    <Serializable> _
    Public Class oName
        Public Property Firstname As String
        Public Property Lastname As String
        Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Fill the list with **500.000** objects:

```
 oNames.cNames.Clear()
 For i As Integer = 1 To 500000
     oNames.cNames.Add(New oNames.oName With {.Firstname = "MyFirstName" & i.ToString, .Lastname = "MyLastName" & i.ToString})
 Next
```

**Write to binary file** (using my own serializer class):

```
 WCC.BinSerialization.ToFile(oNames.cNames, "c:\temp\ObjToBin.bin", IO.FileMode.Append)
```

**Write to XML file** (using my own serializer class):

```
 WCC.XMLSerialization.Obj_To_XMLFile(oNames.cNames, "c:\temp\ObjToXML.xml")
```

**Write to XML-string** (using my own serializer class):

```
 Dim XMLStr As String
 XMLStr = WCC.XMLSerialization.Obj_To_XLMStr(oNames.cNames)
```

My serializer class:

```
 Public Class WCC
     Public Class XMLSerialization

       Public Shared Function Obj_To_XLMStr(Obj As Object) As String
          Using SW As New System.IO.StringWriter
              Dim X As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Obj.GetType)
              X.Serialize(SW, Obj)
              Return SW.ToString
           End Using
       End Function

       Public Shared Sub XMLStr_To_Obj(XMLString As String, ByRef ListObj As Object)
           Using SR As New System.IO.StringReader(XMLString)
              Dim X As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ListObj.GetType)
              ListObj = X.Deserialize(SR)
           End Using
       End Sub

       Public Shared Sub Obj_To_XMLFile(Obj As Object, Path As String)
           Dim XWS As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
           XWS.Indent = True
           XWS.IndentChars = vbTab
           Using XW As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(Path, XWS)
              Dim X As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Obj.GetType)
              X.Serialize(XW, Obj)
           End Using
       End Sub
     End Class

     Public Class BinSerialization
       Public Shared Sub ToFile(Obj As Object, Path As String, FileMode As IO.FileMode)
           Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(Path, FileMode)
              Dim bf As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
              bf.Serialize(fs, Obj)
           End Using
       End Sub
     End Class
 End Class
```

Comment: It seems the .net BinaryFormatter just perform very bad.
It just tried the 3rd part protobuf-net class
Write 500.000 to binary file: 717ms
Read 500.000 from binary file: 1102ms and filesize 18,3MB