# vb.net: reading binary into a project

Tags: vb.net, binary, filestream

I am trying to save a project's properties into a file when the .exe is close and reload them when the .exe opens up again.  I tried saving as an .xml but was getting exceptions thrown, so I instead tried to save as a binary file like so:

```
Dim savedProject As New classProject
savedProject = project

Dim fileName As String
fileName = project.name

Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(project.directory & "\" & project.name & ".bin", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    bf.Serialize(fs, savedProject)
End Using
```

With the help of this forum, I've seen plenty of examples online now of how to save to a file in this manner, but I'm struggling to find how to reload this file upon reloading the .exe.

Comment: [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25319489/1070452)  Whether it works well or not depends on what is on `classProject`

Comment: Thank you.  When reading the file back, do I need to provide a file path?

Comment: BTW you are not just saving a binary file, but serializing an object (which is why that class will be important).  yes, you need to supply the full path ("reading back" == deserializing) and that is not the best way to create one (Use `Path.Combine`)

Comment: Thank you again.  I wasn't aware of Path.Combine

Comment: If you have several projects, you can store them in a List<T> and serialize them all at once (rather than one per file) [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25880148/1070452) It uses a Collection<T> instead of a List, but the concepts are the same.  If the links help, upvote them

Comment: Thanks, your first link was spot on with what I needed and every thing is working great now.  The other link was also very informative

Answer (score 0):

You could use my generic-usage serialization snippet to serialize and deserialize from Xml or Binary.

An example usage would be this:

```
Dim obj As String() = {"Hello World!"}
SerializationUtil.Serialize(obj, "C:\File.bin", SerializationFormat.Binary)

obj = SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of String())("C:\File.bin", SerializationFormat.Binary)
```

Source-code:

```
' ***********************************************************************
' Author   : Elektro
' Modified : 10-November-2015
' ***********************************************************************

#Region " Public Members Summary "

#Region " Methods "

' SerializationUtil.Serialize(Of T)(T, String, SerializationFormat)
' SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of T)(T, String, SerializationFormat)

#End Region

#Region " Functions "

' SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of T)(String, SerializationFormat) As T
' SerializationUtil.IsObjectSerializable(Of T)(T, SerializationFormat) As Boolean
' SerializationUtil.IsTypeSerializable(Of T)() As Boolean
' SerializationUtil.IsTypeSerializable(Of T)(T) As Boolean

#End Region

#End Region

#Region " Option Statements "

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

#End Region

#Region " Imports "

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

#End Region

#Region " Serialization Util "

''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Contains serialization related utilities.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example for Binary serialization/deserialization.
''' <code>
''' Dim obj As String() = {"item1", "item2", "item3"}
''' SerializationUtil.Serialize(obj, "C:\File.bin", SerializationFormat.Binary)
''' 
''' obj = SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of String())("C:\File.bin", SerializationFormat.Binary)
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example for Xml serialization/deserialization.
''' <code>
''' Dim obj As String() = {"item1", "item2", "item3"}
''' SerializationUtil.Serialize(obj, "C:\File.xml", SerializationFormat.Xml)
''' 
''' obj = SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of String())("C:\File.xml", SerializationFormat.Xml)
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Module SerializationUtil

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Serializes the data of an Object to the specified file, using the specified serialization format.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="obj">
    ''' The object to be serialized.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="filepath">
    ''' The filepath where to save the serialized data.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="format">
    ''' The serialization format.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub Serialize(Of T)(ByVal obj As T,
                               ByVal filepath As String,
                               ByVal format As SerializationFormat)

        Dim serializer As Object = SerializationUtil.GetSerializer(obj, format)

        Using fs As New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)

            Select Case serializer.GetType

                Case GetType(BinaryFormatter)
                    DirectCast(serializer, BinaryFormatter).Serialize(fs, obj)

                Case GetType(XmlSerializer)
                    DirectCast(serializer, XmlSerializer).Serialize(fs, obj)

            End Select

        End Using

    End Sub

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Deserializes the data of an Object from the specified file, using the specified serialization format.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="filepath">
    ''' The filepath where from deserialize the serialized data.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="format">
    ''' The serialization format.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal filepath As String,
                                      ByVal format As SerializationFormat) As T

        Dim serializer As Object = SerializationUtil.GetSerializer(Of T)(format)

        Using fs As New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)

            Select Case serializer.GetType

                Case GetType(BinaryFormatter)
                    Return DirectCast(DirectCast(serializer, BinaryFormatter).Deserialize(fs), T)

                Case GetType(XmlSerializer)
                    Return DirectCast(DirectCast(serializer, XmlSerializer).Deserialize(fs), T)

            End Select

        End Using

    End Function

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Deserializes the data of an Object from the specified file, using the specified serialization format.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="filepath">
    ''' The filepath where from deserialize the serialized data.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="format">
    ''' The serialization format.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub Deserialize(Of T)(ByRef refObj As T,
                                 ByVal filepath As String,
                                 ByVal format As SerializationFormat)

        refObj = SerializationUtil.Deserialize(Of T)(filepath, format)

    End Sub

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified <see cref="Type"/> can be serialized.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' The <see cref="Type"/> to check.
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <see langword="True"/> if the specified <see cref="Type"/> can be serialized; otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function IsTypeSerializable(Of T)() As Boolean

        Return Attribute.IsDefined(GetType(T), GetType(SerializableAttribute))

    End Function

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified <see cref="Type"/> can be serialized.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="type">
    ''' The <see cref="Type"/> to check.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <see langword="True"/> if the specified <see cref="Type"/> can be serialized; otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function IsTypeSerializable(Of T)(ByVal type As T) As Boolean

        Return SerializationUtil.IsTypeSerializable(Of T)()

    End Function

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified object can be serialized.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="obj">
    ''' The object to check.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <see langword="True"/> if the specified object can be serialized; otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function IsObjectSerializable(Of T)(ByVal obj As T,
                                               ByVal format As SerializationFormat) As Boolean

        Dim serializer As Object = SerializationUtil.GetSerializer(obj, format)

        Using ms As New MemoryStream

            Try
                Select Case serializer.GetType

                    Case GetType(BinaryFormatter)
                        DirectCast(serializer, BinaryFormatter).Serialize(ms, obj)

                    Case GetType(XmlSerializer)
                        DirectCast(serializer, XmlSerializer).Serialize(ms, obj)

                End Select

                Return True

            Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                Return False

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw

            End Try

        End Using

    End Function

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the proper data serializer.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="format">
    ''' The serialization format.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">
    ''' Bad Serialization Format.
    ''' </exception>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Function GetSerializer(Of T)(ByVal format As SerializationFormat) As Object

        Select Case format

            Case SerializationFormat.Binary
                Return New BinaryFormatter

            Case SerializationFormat.Xml
                Return New XmlSerializer(type:=GetType(T))

            Case Else
                Throw New ArgumentException(message:="Bad Serialization Format.", paramName:="format")

        End Select

    End Function

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the proper data serializer.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <typeparam name="T">
    ''' </typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="obj">
    ''' The object to check.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="format">
    ''' The serialization format.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">
    ''' Bad Serialization Format.
    ''' </exception>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Function GetSerializer(Of T)(ByVal obj As T,
                                         ByVal format As SerializationFormat) As Object

        Select Case format

            Case SerializationFormat.Binary
                Return New BinaryFormatter

            Case SerializationFormat.Xml
                Return New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)

            Case Else
                Throw New ArgumentException(message:="Bad Serialization Format.", paramName:="format")

        End Select

    End Function

#End Region

End Module

#End Region
```